# Java abstraction return value

Tags: java, class, reflection

Assuming that I have this abstract class `Base` that a lot of my other classes extend....

What must I write in the method prototype in order to return the Object that was extended?

Example:

```
public abstract class Base{
    public static Base returnABC(final String key){
        return abcMap.get(key);
    }

    public static ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Base> returnABCMap(){
        return abcMap;
    }
}
```

What must be written in place of `Base` to return the Object ABC (or something else) to have the following effect:

```
public abstract class Base{
    public static ABC returnABC(final String key){
        return abcMap.get(key);
    }

    public static ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, ABC> returnABCMap(){
        return abcMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this returnABC in your abstract class...? PLease provide the abstract class and some more code if possible

Comment: yes, the methods are in the abstract class.

Comment: In that case you should write Base as return type in your abstract class and ABC as return type in your child class

Comment: No, that is not the objective of this question because I already know that. What I am aiming for, is an effect like the Map/Set return values. With the angled brackets, the compiler understands the return type and checks for it, and the return type is always correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method will return an instance of Base.  If ABC extends Base, you will merely create the instance of ABC and return it as an instance of Base.  It's polymorphism at work.

The return type on the overridden function may also be altered to only return ABC instead of any instance of BASE.

**See the comments below for the actual answer.**

Comment: What I am aiming for, is an effect like the Map/Set return values. With the angled brackets (something similar is acceptable) the compiler understands the return type and checks for it, and the return type is always correct in a way the descendant does not need to check for it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do that? What value does it provide?

Comment: Ok, wait...  Do you mean that you want to limit the set or map. Example. public Set<? extends Base> set;

Comment: I am unable to reveal much, but lets just say that the program uses the facade design pattern and I am pretty sick of casting and am looking for alternatives.

Comment: I think this is what you are trying to achieve public static ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, ? extends BASE> returnABCMap() or you can write in extended class ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, ? extends ABC> returnABCMap() as long as ABC is a subordinate class of Base.

Answer (score 0):

Both your base class and child class then should return the Base object. To use it appropriately you then have to typecast it.